# Restrições de rotas com laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.3

Boa tarde.

Como posso fazer uma restrição de algumas rotas específicas com Laravel?

Por exemplo. Se eu tiver um e-commerce eu terei os usuários administradores que poderão acessar as rotas do painel administrativo e todas as outras rotas do site. Mas também terei os usuários/clientes digamos assim. Esses poderão acessar as rotas do site e de seu login na área de cliente, porém não poderão acessar as rotas do painel administrativo.

Um outro exemplo:

Rotas
(/admin/home) (/admin/produtos) (/admin/editar-produtos) -> Essas rotas apenas os administradores poderão acessar.

(/minhas-compras) (/meu-carrinho) -> Essas rotas os clientes e os administradores poderão acessar.

Porém se eu fizer a mesma autenticação para os usuários/clientes e para os administradores, eu não conseguirei fazer essa restrição. Se o cara estiver logado ele conseguirá acessar qualquer rota do meu sistema, independentemente dele ser administrador ou cliente.

Entenderam? Podem me ajudar?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode usar os Middlewares do Laravel, você cria uma regra especifica e cria um agrupamento de rotas por exemplo:

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth','check_permissions']], function () {
   // TODAS SUAS ROTAS QUE VÃO SER VALIDADAS POR ESSE MIDDLEWARE
})
```

Nesse agrupamento, eu estou dizendo que ele tem que estar autenticado e respeitar as regras do `Middleware` ***CheckPermissions***

meu arquivo CheckPermissions:

```
class CheckPermissions {

     /**
       * Handle an incoming request.
       *
       * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request $request
       * @param  \Closure $next
       * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle ($request, \Closure $next)
    {
        $isAdmin = Auth::user()->is_admin;

        if ($isAdmin) {
            return $next($request);
        }
        return redirect()->route('home');
    }

}
```

Ele irá verificar se o usuário é admin, caso não for redireciona para home, caso contrário segue para a rota que está sendo solicitada.

Você tem que adicionar seu middleware no arquivo Kernel.php
na variável `$routeMiddleware`:

```
protected $routeMiddleware = [
        'auth' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\Authenticate::class,
        'auth.basic' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\AuthenticateWithBasicAuth::class,
        'bindings' => \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class,
        'can' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\Authorize::class,
        'guest' => \App\Http\Middleware\RedirectIfAuthenticated::class,
        'throttle' => \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\ThrottleRequests::class,
        'check_permissions' => CheckPermissions::class
    ];
```

Caso tenha dúvidas, segue link da documentação:

https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/middleware

Comment: Boa tarde. Vou implementar aqui e te dou um retorno. Desde já agradeço a ajuda.

Comment: Bom dia. Funcionou! Obrigado parceiro.

Comment: De nada @MaurícioBiléssimo se puder aceitar a resposta como correta, agradeço! Abraço